# To separate string containing semi colon using BR()

Tags: formula

I have a field which has string concatenated via ;
for example- If my string is A; B; C then i want to convert it into:

```
A
B
C
```

using BR() in formula field. Is it possible to do this via formula field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of substitute and break formula as shown below:

```
SUBSTITUTE(<Your Field API name here>, ';', BR())
```

Note that use of excessive # of formula fields is not advisable since they get calculated during runtime and might cause performance issues (esp. in large data volume orgs)

Comment: Formula fields are calculated when queried and not otherwise. I am not really sure what your warning is about.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm :)

Comment: @PhilW I'm aware that formula fields are calculated when queried (via SOQL or displayed in page layout/ list views/ reports). In large data volume orgs, I would be cautious about creating too many formula fields and using them (for example in list view or reports) which could translate into increased load time. It was more like an FYI to the OP.

Comment: Sp it is not so much about the creation of the formula fields, but rather the usage.

Comment: @PhilW Yes, that was the intent behind that line.